# MySql select query with html tags like <b> ..</b>

Tags: mysql

I have a situation where i cannot edit the results from mysql query in php. (I am using codecharge studio which has few limitations ). I need to highlight certain items in the combobox. 
Just a weird question, is there any way to write a  mysql select query that returns value with html tags in around it?

For example

select **name** from useres where managerId = 6.

Or any other equivalent statement?

Comment: if you can change your output query write: select concat('<b>', name, '</b>') from useres where managerId = 6. Then by your app you must manage this result. If you can change your app, wirte normally your query and then apply format tags on your result text.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use any SQL commands in the Codecharge query - in a Table query they are mainly limited to simple conversions like trim() and concat(), but if you change the Query type to 'SQL' query and you can go wild. You can do UNIONs and CASE statements etc etc.

As for putting formatting within select OPTIONS, from what I've found it's very flakey and browser dependent (FF worked, Safari & Chrome did not, in a quick test), using CSS styles in the `option`

```
<html><head>
 <style type="text/css"> 
   option { 
      font: normal normal normal 10px arial,helvetica,sans-serif; 
      color: #0f0; 
  } 
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="" method="post">
   <select name="number">
     <option value="1" style="font-weight:bold">One</option>
     <option value="2" style="font-family : monospace; font-size : 12pt">=Two=</option>
     <option value="3"><em>Three</em></option>
   </select>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

For the browsers that work, the styles in the `option` work, but HTML tags within the display don't (ie: `<em>Three</em>`)

As for how to do the styles in CodeCharge, you can probably (I haven't checked against `option` but can be against the `select`) create 'Attributes' and set values in code such as the CSS styles depending on value (Before Show event).

See CodeCharge Manual for 'Component Attributes' and 'Working with Component Attributes'